# Get actual <body> font size using jQuery

Tags: jquery, font-size

is there an easy way to get actual font size in jQuery? I'm using media queries to display website differently on different sizes of displays, and on the same website there is a gallery, which has dimensions measured in pixels not in ems. I'd like to write a function which gets actual  font size, depends on screen resolution currently displaying, and use it to get an aprioprate gallery size when resolution changes. Thanks in advance, greets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
  $("body").css('font-size')
```

Comment: Yes! This is correct! I can't believe it was THAT simple;) Even when I change font size from 100% to, let's say, 120% using css media-screen, it gives me actual basic <body> font size (I checked browser's console), now I can resize any elemets using ems :)

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
$("body").html().length
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work, I looked into console, it gives weird number of 13053, and it's not actual font size...